# wordpress customizr theme show logo and title

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using customizr theme, I want to show both a logo and a title in header part. but I can show only one item at a time. as per this documentation http://www.themesandco.com/customizr/ theme set title if there is no logo. I want to show both, is there any way for this ? I want to show logo and on left side a company name. plz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a the *__after_logo* hook with the following code. (to copy and paste in your functions.php file of your child theme or your theme).

```
add_action( '__after_logo' , 'display_my_site_title');
function display_my_site_title() {
    //first checks if there is a logo uploaded
    $logo_src               = esc_url ( tc__f( '__get_option' , 'tc_logo_upload') ) ;
    if ( empty($logo_src) ) 
        return;

   //then print the site title after
    printf('<h1><a class="site-title" href="%1$s" title="%2$s | %3$s">%4$s</a></h1>',
        esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
        esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name') ),
        esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ),
        esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name') )
    );
}
```

The code has been tested and works. (you have to have at least v3.0.14 of the theme)

I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to adjust the following file:

customizr\parts\class-header-header_main.php

You're right that it will show the title or the logo, as per comment in the file:

LINE 115  The template for displaying the title or the logo